# What is the difference between "System debug logs" and "Monitoring debug logs"

Tags: debug-logs

The Salesforce article on debug logs (currently found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_monitoring_debug_logs.htm&type=5)) states that "System debug logs are retained for 24 hours. Monitoring debug logs are retained for seven days."

What is the difference between a System debug log and a monitoring debug log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For system logs, Location is SystemLog. System logs are generated as
> part of system log monitoring, such as while you use Developer
> Console, and are visible only to you.
>
> For monitoring logs, Location is Monitoring. Monitoring logs are
> generated when your org has active CLASS_TRACING or USER_DEBUG trace
> flags. These logs are visible to all your org’s admins.

Refer to this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_debug_log_delete.htm&type=5).